# Core Data model version with new entity

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am unable to migrate my project to a new model version, and I have created the smallest project possible to highlight my issue, and hope that someone can show me what's wrong with my approach.

I have the project in GitHub: [MigrateApp](https://github.com/imyrvold/MigrateApp.git)

I create a new project in Xcode, call it `MigrateApp`, choose SwiftUI and hook on the checkbox for Core Data. This should also work with UIKit, because I am not doing anything with the UI.

I immediately run the app, and click the plus button in the upper right a couple of times, to populate the Core Data with some items.

Then I stop the app from Xcode, and click the Core Data `MigrateApp` in Xcode. I click the `Editor` menu and choose `Add Model Version`. I choose the name `MigrateApp v2`. And I set the current model version to the new version, so that the green checkmark shows in `MigrateApp v2`.

The entities in `MigrateApp v2` shows only one entity, called `Item`. I now want to add a new entity called `Subitem`, that have a one-to-one relation to `Item`. I add the `Subitem` entity, and adds two attributes, `date` with type Date and `text` with type String, both non-optional.
[image]

Then I add relationship `sub` to `Item`, with destination `Subitem`, and relationship `item` to `Subitem` with destination `Item`, and sets the inverse of both relationships.
[image]

Add a new file, choose `Mapping Model` type, set the source to `MigrateApp.xcdatamodel` and target data model to `MigrateApp v2.xcdatamodel`. Give it the name `Modelv1Tov2`.

I think that I have done everything correct up to now, so the next steps I am not quite sure I do correctly.

I open the `Modelv1Tov2` mapping model file in Xcode, and sets the source of the `Subitem` entity mapping to `Item` in the `Entity Mapping` panel. This renames the `Subitem` to `ItemToSubitem`.

Clicking the `ItemToItem`, I see that the relationship mappings show `sub`. I click on `sub`, and sets the Key Path in Relationship Mapping to `$source.sub`, and mapping name to `ItemToSubitem`.
[image]

Likewise with `ItemToSubitem`, I click `item` relationship mappings, and set Key Path to `$source.item` and mapping name to `ItemToItem`.
[image]

The last thing I need to do, is ensure that Xcode migrate the database automatically, and don't try to infer the migration but use the migration mapping. Add the two lines to `Persistence.swift` in the init, after setting the `container` property:
`container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MigrateApp")`

```swift
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MigrateApp")
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = false
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
}
```

When I now runs the app again from Xcode, it crashes with the message: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSManagedObject 0x600001d1fcf0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Item is not key value coding-compliant for the key "item".'`

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. The minimal code should be in the question not as a link.

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: No code is added to the project, beside the two Swift lines above. The Core Data changes are all described in the steps, but I could include images to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for answers to this problem, and I found that I do not need to set the `shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true` and `shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = false`. If I let Core Data infer the  migration, the migration will be successful. So I remade the steps above for a fresh project, and skipped the step where I added the two lines to `Persistence.swift`, and also skipped the step adding a mapping model, and the migration was successful. I would still want to know why I had the crash when using the mapping model, and will investigate that issue further.